# array en postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Deseo insertar el resultado de un select en una columna de una tabla esta columna es de tipo  `text[]` y la variable donde almaceno el select tambien es del mismo tipo lo que deseo insertar son los registros de los últimos 60 minutos, pero el problema es que solo me inserta esto `{}` en la columna...alguien puede ayudarme..
dejo la consulta que hago:
gracias..

```
tam_min=(SELECT array(SELECT txt_tamanio FROM cat.tamanio_tab WHERE txt_nombre_tab=tabla AND dt_registro > now()-INTERVAL '60 minutes' AND dt_registro < now()));
```

Comment: alguna idea? o tengo algun error en mi consulta?

Answer (score 1):

tu consulta parece bien, lo que es muy probable que no se cumpla la condición que estas filtrando con el WHERE (tal vez la debas revisar), usando tu misma idea te muestro  un ejemplo:

```
--con datos 
postgres=# SELECT array(SELECT datname::text FROM pg_database limit 5);
array
--------------------------------------------
{postgres,stat_record,test,template0,dell}
(1 fila)
--sin datos {}, la condicion del where no cumple con nada y retorna el arreglo vacio
postgres=# SELECT array(SELECT datname::text FROM pg_database where datname like 'as%' limit 5);
array 
------- 
{}
(1 fila)
```

Comment: Gracias..lo checare

Comment: Sin duda era eso no cumplia con el where..Nunca le asignaba el tipo de hora de la fecha (TIME)..como yo queria solo minutos debia de asignarle un tipo..asi quedo WHERE txt_nombre_tab=tabla AND dt_registro::TIME > now()::TIME-INTERVAL